# Sending tweets to Tumblr

Tags: html, twitter, tumblr

I'm setting up a Tumblr blog and i would like to see tweets appear in the stream.

This page:http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes

and this page: http://tumblring.net/how-to-send-your-twitter-updates-to-tumblr-automatically/

seem to suggest its possible, but when i follow those instructions, nothing. I am putting that code within {block:posts}{/block:posts}

Also can find nothing else on the web about it, maybe its an old feature that no longer works?

Comment: Do you want tweets to appear only on your blog's page, or also on your followers' dashboards? If the latter, you won't be able to accomplish it using custom themes.

Comment: If you want to post new tweets to your dashboard, let me suggest [IfThisThanThat](https://ifttt.com) You don't need any technical knowledge whatsoever and it's (currently) free.